# Android WebView Grid Display

Tags: android, android-webview

I am having some problems with a webview I am using to access a specific URL within my Activity. When I load this exact same URL on a PC browser such as firefox, the edges of the grid are displayed

[image: PC]

When I try to load the same URL from within my WebView by using

```
webView.loadURL("www.url.com");
```

I get the following grid.

[image: Android]

Any ideas on how I can fix this? It's not a major issue, just annoying.

And this isn't real data, so don't worry about that.

I don't know that much about HTML so maybe this is an HTML issue?
Apologize for using imageshack, I can't post images yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried scrolling to the side?  Does it display the images, then?

You might try the following:

[Building webpages to support different screen densities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

Take a look at the Android documentation there.  It should give you a good example of how to get your data to display properly on any device.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I don't know that much about HTML, but here's what I did. As it explains in that section, modifying the meta tags in an html file can help displaying on mobile devices. I got the page I'm trying to load's source code and saved it as a local HTML file. I then made a dummy app that just loads that file within a webview. I modified the meta tag as described in the link you provided but, still, the edges don't display. I tried targeting low, med, and high dpi as well as the option that scales it based on the device itself. The edges still don't display.

Comment: it might be possible that the settings on the WebKit browser are set such that this styling is not shown... is it a simple `<table> ... <tr>content</tr> </table>` component, or something more complex?

Comment: It is a table, but a more complex table.

`<table cellpadding="0" rules="none" border="0" style="empty-cells: show; width:8in; height:10.5in; overflow: hidden; table-layout:fixed;">`

is the declaration I believe. I think you're right though. I search and replaced all instances of "hidden" with "visable" in the HTML file. The formatting is messed up on the device obviously, but the edges of the grid are displayed.

Comment: Ah! And when I just change the hidden/visable tag in the declaration, the edges of the grid appear. Well done sir/madam.

Comment: visible* sorry. Apparently spelling it "visable" also works, but probably not a good idea.